# Apache 'Catch All'

Tags: apache-2.2

I would act something `http://e.ggtimer.com/` when you request `http://e.ggtimer.com/5minutes` the server sends the `5minutes` to a script the server so it can do something.

I have an apache 2.2.17 server running on arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod_rewrite enabled, you can add an .htaccess file to catch everything with the following rules / configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) yourmainscriptfile.php?timer=$1
```

This would forward every REQUEST_URI to that single script and place it as a value of the timer $_GET variable.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I also found this link which helped me understand mod_rewrite a little better. http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax